# C# using HttpWebRequest doesn't work

Tags: c#

At the time of opening, using `HttpWebRequest`. Why are visiting

https://web4.sa8888.net/sport/Games.aspx?lang=3&device=pc

Can't get the data inside?

```
string strResult = "";
try
{
    string url = "https://web4.sa8888.net/sport/Games.aspx?lang=3&device=pc";

    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

    request.Method = "GET";
    request.Timeout = 30000;
    request.KeepAlive = true; 
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
    request.Headers.Set("Pragma", "no-cache");
    //request.ContentLength = bs.Length;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream streamReceive = response.GetResponseStream();
    Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(streamReceive, encoding);
    strResult = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
textBox1.Text=strResult;
```

Comment: What do you get? An exception, an empty sting or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you've linked to is built using javascript so what you are seeing is not raelly part of the source. If you look at for example https://web4.sa8888.net/js/v1000/sport/games/IceHockey.js you will see that they build alot of the table data there.

HttpWebRequest will only fetch a file for you, it won't run javascript and such like a real browser would. Thats why you are not getting the data you want.

After looking at it a bit more it seems like they are streaming information in a binary format via websockets so this is a very non-trivial setup to get the data out (and probably at least partially built to avoid people scraping their data).

Comment: hi Karl-JohanSjögren

So how should my program be rewritten?
HttpWebRequest+websockets?
Or which side has examples to refer to?
thank you

Comment: Websockets seems to be required yes, but it would need a lot of more research/reverse engineering to figure out how to implement this. It is way to large for an answer here on SO. Go read up on websockets and then start reading the JavaScript files on that site to figure out how it works exactly, that's the best advice I can give you.

Comment: Ok i try
Thank you for your answer